# How to get all parametrs from get request in Param in their sequence

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlets

I have such get request: localhost:8080/check?id=10&id=1&num=2&id=13

I get params like this:

```
@GetMapping("/check")
@ResponseBody
public void getCheck(@RequestParam LinkedMultiValueMap<String,Long> ex){
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

Console: {id=[10, 1, 13], num=[2]}

But I need to get all data in its sequence like this:
{id=[10],id=[1],num=[2],id=[13]}

How can I do this?

Comment: Why is the sequence important? That shouldn't really matter... Also you won't get them in sequence because when multiple arguments with the same name are submitted it is treated as an array underneath.

Comment: @M.Deinum Because after id goes number, but if it doesn't, that means the number is 1

Comment: WIthout checking the full string of the request that isn't possible. Due to arguments with the same name being send will be interpreted as an array. You probably should be considering using a different way like passing matrix variables (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-matrix-variables)